# Gtihub Action fails unpextedly at npm ci

Tags: reactjs, npm, github-actions

I have a github action which build react app. It worked fine until today and fails unexpectedly at npm ci action.It used to run smooth everytime.When I try to run my app in local it works fine as well.
Below is the error from Actions output:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   dev react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   43 more (@egoist/vue-to-react, @emotion/core, @emotion/react, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN node_modules/@mui/base
npm WARN   @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.60" from @mui/material@5.2.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@mui/material
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN   node_modules/@mui/base
npm WARN     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.60" from @mui/material@5.2.4
npm WARN     node_modules/@mui/material
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   dev react-dom@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   14 more (@ramonak/react-progress-bar, @restart/ui, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^17.0.2" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN node_modules/@mui/base
npm WARN   @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.60" from @mui/material@5.2.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@mui/material
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^17.0.2" from @mui/base@5.0.0-alpha.60
npm WARN   node_modules/@mui/base
npm WARN     @mui/base@"5.0.0-alpha.60" from @mui/material@5.2.4
npm WARN     node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/icons-material@5.2.4
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.6 || ^17" from @egoist/vue-to-react@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@egoist/vue-to-react
npm ERR!     @egoist/vue-to-react@"^1.1.0" from @storybook/addon-docs@5.3.21
npm ERR!     node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs
npm ERR!       @storybook/addon-docs@"^5.3.4" from symphony-bdk-ui-toolkit@1.0.2-beta.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/symphony-bdk-ui-toolkit
npm ERR!         dev symphony-bdk-ui-toolkit@"^1.0.2-beta.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   42 more (@emotion/core, @emotion/react, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!   @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2" from @mui/icons-material@5.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/icons-material
npm ERR!     @mui/icons-material@"^5.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/runner/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-06-16T02_22_34_913Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is my yaml file of my github workflow :

```
name: Build and Push to GCP (Production)

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GKE_PROJECT: sym-prod
  DOCKER_IMAGE: gcr.io/sym/contactApp
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: JAVA-${{ github.sha }}
  SNYK_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SNYK_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  test-build-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install NPM Packages
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build App
        run: |
          REACT_APP_BUILD_SHA=${{ github.sha }} \
          REACT_APP_BUILD_DATE=$(date +'%F %T %Z') \
          npm run build-for-java
      - name: Build Docker
        run: docker build -t ${{ env.DOCKER_IMAGE }} -f Dockerfile .
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4664#issuecomment-1085910198 worked for me where I had to pin npm to 8.5.5.

Comment: Hi @Haunted, can you tell me where to pin npm to 8.5.5 ?